# Unable to run docker node.js application

Tags: node.js, docker

I am new to Docker , so I may not be able to frame my question correctly.

I have created an image for my node js application by using below command.

```
 docker build -t ramakishore/nodeapp .
```

I have created a container for this image by executing below command

```
docker run -p 49160:8080 -d ramakishore/nodeapp
```

docker ps command displays

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
ca64b61afca7        ramakishore/nodeapp   "npm start"         6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:49160->8080/tcp   gigantic_swanson
```

Contents of my dockerFile are

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

When I type http://localhost:8080 in chrome , I was expecting my node page to be displayed, but instead "This site can’t be reached" is displayed.

Any idea what is the mistake I doing.

Comment: http://localhost:49160 is your port...

Comment: for localhost:49160  also same issue..

Comment: What enviroment are you on? Are you using docker for windows or docker on windows. If you are using docker on windows you will have a virtual mashine in virtualbox, and then you won't be able to reach localhost, then you will need to go to the adress of the virtual mashine

Comment: I am using docker toolbox for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would check to see if your application is running inside your docker container by entering the container and looking at what is running:

```
$ docker exec -ti ca64b61afca7
$ ps aux
```

Then check to make sure it's listening on the correct port (and on 0.0.0.0):

```
$ netstat -tunlp
```

Next I would try a curl from inside the container:

```
$ curl localhost:8080
```

If this works, your app is running correctly and the issue lies between your container and your host.

Next I would exit the docker container (`ctrl + d`) and try to hit the app from the host:

```
$ curl localhost:49160
```

**Note**: If you're on a Mac or Windows, you may need to hit the IP address of the docker host - you can find this IP by doing an `echo $DOCKER_HOST` (or on Windows `echo %DOCKER_HOST%`.

E.g., if your `DOCKER_HOST` is 192.168.1.50 you would do a:

```
curl 192.168.1.50:49160
```

Comment: using "ip" instead of "localhost" helped , now it's working...thanks